# Rails - Find missing keys between different locales (.yml files)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locale, yaml, routines

I have 2 locale files **en.yml** and **pt.yml**. There are some keys that exist only on **pt.yml** and other keys that exist only on **en.yml**

Is there a method or routine to list all these keys? (Just comparing the two files)

Example output:

```
en.activerecord.attributes.person.hand
pt.activerecord.models.bird
```

Obs: something other than the  `i18n-tasks missing` task.

Answer (score 4):

I find this solution work perfect. It's from a blog post of Kisko Labs. Reference is here: http://blog.kiskolabs.com/post/908453942/comparing-rails-locale-files-for-missing

```rb
LOCALE_1 = "~/Code/project/config/locales/fi.yml"
LOCALE_2 = "~/Code/project/config/locales/en.yml"
    
require 'yaml'
    
def flatten_keys(hash, prefix="")
  keys = []
  hash.keys.each do |key|
    if hash[key].is_a? Hash
      current_prefix = prefix + "#{key}."
      keys << flatten_keys(hash[key], current_prefix)
    else
      keys << "#{prefix}#{key}"
    end
  end
  prefix == "" ? keys.flatten : keys
end
 
def compare(locale_1, locale_2)
  yaml_1 = YAML.load(File.open(File.expand_path(locale_1)))
  yaml_2 = YAML.load(File.open(File.expand_path(locale_2)))

  keys_1 = flatten_keys(yaml_1[yaml_1.keys.first])
  keys_2 = flatten_keys(yaml_2[yaml_2.keys.first])

  missing = keys_2 - keys_1
  file = locale_1.split('/').last
  if missing.any?
    puts "Missing from #{file}:"
    missing.each { |key| puts "  - #{key}" }
  else
    puts "Nothing missing from #{file}."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
require 'set'
require 'yaml'

files = ['en.yml', 'pt.yml']

p files.map {| file_path| YAML.load(File.read(file_path))}
  .map {|object| Set.new(object.keys) }
  .reduce(:^)
```

Docs: [YAML](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) and [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)